# X-editable toggle edit on click of custom edit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I have a strange problem with the X-editable plugin for twitter-bootstrap.

What i am trying to do is trigger the 'Edit' popup screen on a button that is on the screen.

The problem is that the 'popup' div only stays on the DOM for less then a second.

I will put some example code below. I am not sure if this has something todo with the plugin/ or bootstrap.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#questionDescription').editable();

    $('.descriptionEditButton').on('click', function(e) {
        $('#questionDescription').editable('toggle');
    });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="questionDescription" data-type="textarea" data-pk="1" data-placeholder="stackOVerflowRocks" data-title="Stack" style="display: inline;">
    foo bar
</a>
<i class="btn icon-edit descriptionEditButton pull-right"></i>
```

What makes it even stranger is when i run the 'toggle' in chrome console the popup is shown.
Thank you!

Comment: why are you trying to edit within an `<a>` tag? Highly doubt that form controls are valid children

Comment: Why don't you make life easy for yourself and put the `i` inside the `a`?

Comment: Thank you very much Rory it solved my problem!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried setting toggle to manual? Something like :

```
$('#questionDescription').editable(
    toggle: 'manual'
);
```